# How can I make the Tablayout also scrollable

Tags: android

I wrote this code,but the tablayout is not scrollable,instead all the tabs shifting towards left, but view pager is working properly.

When I scroll viewpager,tab items are moving,I want the tabitems should be scrollable with tablayout.

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorblue"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorgeydark"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorwhite"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorgeydark"
        android:layout_marginTop="5.5dp"
        app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:tabContentStart="0dp"
        />


    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tablayout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);

Comment: @rajkavadia it is the same with `app:tabMode="scrollable"`

Comment: No,just try it.sometime it works

Comment: I tried both the solution, still not working, effect is same @rajkavadia Gabriele  Mariotti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app:tabGravity="center"`  only works with 
`app:tabMode="fixed"`
So if you want to make tab scrollable and center aligned then you have to set tab mode to fixed else tab will be left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener to the viewPager and a TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener to the tabLayout

//kotlin sample

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout))
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
   override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
      //here the view pager will change
      viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.position, false)
   }

   override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

   }

   override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

   }
})
```